# Group by, with rank and sum - not getting correct output

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to sum a column with rank function and group by month, my code is

```
 select  dbo.UpCase( REPLACE( p.Agent_name,'.',' '))as Agent_name, SUM(convert ( float ,   
  p.Amount))as amount,   
  RANK() over( order by  SUM(convert ( float ,Amount )) desc ) as arank 
  from  dbo.T_Client_Pc_Reg p  
  group by   p.Agent_name ,p.Sale_status ,MONTH(Reg_date)
  having [p].Sale_status='Activated'
```

Currently I'm getting all total value of that column not month wise

```
Name  amount rank 
a     100    1
b     80     2
c     50     3
```

for a amount 100 is  total amount  till now  but , i want  get current month total amount  not  last months..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just need to add a WHERE clause? Here is a minor re-write that I think works generally better. Some setup in tempdb:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.T_Client_Pc_Reg
(
  Agent_name VARCHAR(32),
  Amount INT,
  Sale_Status VARCHAR(32),
  Reg_date DATETIME
);

INSERT dbo.T_Client_Pc_Reg 
          SELECT 'a', 50, 'Activated', GETDATE()
UNION ALL SELECT 'a', 50, 'Activated', GETDATE()
UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 20, 'Activated', GETDATE()
UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 20, 'Activated', GETDATE()
UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 20, 'Activated', GETDATE()
UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 20, 'Activated', GETDATE()
UNION ALL SELECT 'b', 20, 'NotActivated', GETDATE()
UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 25, 'Activated', GETDATE()
UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 25, 'Activated', GETDATE()
UNION ALL SELECT 'c', 25, 'Activated', GETDATE()-40;
```

Then the query:

```
SELECT 
  Agent_name = UPPER(REPLACE(Agent_name, '.', '')),
  Amount = SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, Amount)),
  arank = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(CONVERT(FLOAT, Amount)) DESC)
FROM dbo.T_Client_Pc_Reg
WHERE Reg_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 0)
  AND Reg_date <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) + 1, 0)
  AND Sale_status = 'Activated'
GROUP BY UPPER(REPLACE(Agent_name, '.', ''))
ORDER BY arank;
```

Now cleanup:

```
USE tempdb;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.T_Client_Pc_Reg;
```